# Wrong DFA from NFA. String Does not contains 110

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

I am doing problem [1.g](http://aduni.org/courses/theory/courseware/psets/Problem_Set_01.html).
My Approach is to first create a NFA that accepts this string i.e. all strings having 110. Then converting it into DFA and then complementing it. I have the answer what should I get however my NFA to DFA conversion doesn't work. I don't know why. Can anyone guide me. Thanks. Here is my NFA. Note this is not full answer as there is complement left to be done. But I am stuck in between.

[image: NFSM]

Then I converted it into FSA

This is What I got

[image: My Result]

I know there is a mistake that there should be self loop of 1 on the AC state but from my above NFA, I am unable to obtain it. Is my NFA wrong? Or I have done some mistake in conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third state is wrong.  From state (AB) on input 1, the next state is not (AC), it is (ABC).  Think about it - if you are in state A -or- B, on 1 you can go from A to A, from A to B, or from B to C.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you did the conversion correctly.  You don't show your steps so I can't tell where you went wrong, but check your work again.  If the NFA is in state A and it receives a 1, what states might it go to?  If the NFA is in state C and it receives a 1, what states might it go to?  So what state should the DFA (FSA) go to if it is in state AC and receives a 1?

There appear to be multiple errors in the conversion.  For instance, the edge out of AB also looks incorrect.

Try applying the standard algorithm and running it by hand, one step at a time.

Comment: Yes. My bad, I totally made a mistake. The third state should be ABC. Thanks.